# Lighting for specific type of photo

Tags: lighting, portrait

so i have found a very unique image, and I am wondering what lighting they would have used, and how they get it to this point (image editing?). Any pointers would be helpful, here is the image.[image]

Comment: Please try to describe the effect in your title. Otherwise, this is indistinguishable from millions of possibly completely different questions.

Answer (score 1):

The lighting doesn't look overly complex to me. Mainly I see what looks like a large softbox to camera right, and a hairlight to camera left. I mocked it up using the [virtual lighting studio here](http://www.zvork.fr/vls/):

[image]
[image]

The background gradient could be achieved in a lot of different ways, but likely is just from adding a gel to a strobe. It could just as easily be achieved in Photoshop though.

Post processing of this image - I would have to ask what in particular you are interested in learning about, as I don't see any technique that really stands out.

The real beauty of this image is the "mud" on the model.

Comment: WOW....Thank you! Yeah I guess they must have had a pretty good makeup artist do that.....not really sure....